# Verify input value

Tags: javascript, input

I'm trying to read a value from an input an verify if it's a certain number of my choosing. What I've got so far is:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
var val = parseInt(input.value);

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
 if(val == 1){
   alert('test')
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

But it doesn't work as intented. There is barely any code here so the solution must be simple but I can't find it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no event 'input', maybe try 'blur' ?

Comment: @user3094755 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input here's where I took the event from

Comment: You already store the value before even adding the event listener. The value you test is never updated.

Comment: @Ivar i knew that's going to be something obvious that I'm missing, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put,

```
const input = document.getElementById('input');

var val = parseInt(input.value);
```

inside the listener like below

```js
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  var val = parseInt(input.value);
  if(val == 1){
    alert('test')
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="input">
```

Comment: That solves the problem thanks, also credit to @Ivar who solved it in the comment

Answer (score -1):

Try using a `type` attribute in your `input`.

```
<input type="number" id="input" />
```

And in your JavaScript, use `input.innerHTML` instead of `input.value`, that way it returns the most updated value.
And `'input'` is not a JavaScript Event.

```
input.addEventListener('oninput', function () {});
//Or, The Way I Would Prefer:
input.addEventListener('onchange', function () {});
```

Comment: Adding a `type` makes absolutely no difference. And [`input`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input-input) _is_ a JavaScript event.

Comment: @Ivar There might not be any support for the asker's browser.